# How find this function $xf(x^2)=f(x),x>0$

Tags: analysis

Assmue that $f(x)\in C(0,+\infty)$ and for any $x>0$ have
$$\int_{x}^{x^2}f(t)dt=\int_{1}^{x}f(t)dt$$

Find this $f$

My try: we have
$$2xf(x^2)-f(x)=f(x)\Longrightarrow xf(x^2)=f(x),\forall x>0$$
and then I can't works

Comment: Just intuitively I would look at the $ x > 0 $ constraint and think, "okay, this has to involve a reciprocal or logarithm somewhere, since $0$ is excluded specifically". As a first guess, I will assume a reciprocal (power form) $f(u)=u^c$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. Thus, $x*(x^2)^c=x^c \rightarrow x^{2c+1}=x^c \rightarrow \frac{x^{2c+1}}{x^c}=1 \rightarrow x^{c+1}=1 \rightarrow c=-1$. Thus, $f(u)=\frac{1}{u}$. I doubt this holds up to completeness and rigor, but it's my first start.

Comment: According to my answer, you are essentially correct.

Answer (score 2):

From
$xf(x^2) = f(x)$
we get
$x^2f(x^2) = xf(x)$.

Letting
$g(x) = xf(x)$,
we get
$g(x^2) = g(x)$.

Iterating,
$g(x^{2^n}) = g(x)$
for any
positive integer $n$.

Therefore,
if $|x| < 1$
and $g$ is continuous at $0$,
$g(x) = g(0)$,
so $g$ is constant.

Therefore,
if $\lim_{x\to 0}xf(x)$
exists,
$f(x)=c/x$
where
$c$ is the limit.

As a check,
$f(x) = c/x$
and
$xf(x^2)
=x(c/x^2)
=c/x
$.

Also, in your integral,
$\int_x^{x^2} \frac{c dt}{t}
=c(\ln(x^2)-\ln(x))
-c(2\ln(x)-\ln(x))
=c\ln(x)
=\int_1^{x} \frac{c dt}{t}
$.

Answer (score 0):

From $xf(x^2) = f(x)$, we get $x^2f(x^2) = xf(x)$.
Let
$g(x) = xf(x)$,
we get
$g(x^2) = g(x)$.
So for any $x\in(0,\infty)$, we have
$$g(x)=g\left(x^{^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}\right).$$
By the continuity of $g$ at $1$, we have
$$g(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}g\left(x^{^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}\right)
=g\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}x^{^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}\right)
=g(1)=f(1).$$
So we conclude that
$$f(x)=\frac{f(1)}{x},\ x\in(0,\infty).$$