# Solutions to $\int\limits_x^{x^2} f(t)\ dt=\int\limits_1^x f(t)\ dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Supposing that $f(x)$ is continuous for positive values of $x$, what are the solutions to the equation $\int\limits_x^{x^2} f(t)\ dt=\int\limits_1^x f(t)\ dt$?

Attempt: We can write the LHS as $F(x^2)-F(x)$ for $F$ an antiderivative of $f$

We can write the RHS as $F(x)-F(1)$

So we have $F(x^2)-F(x)=F(x)-F(1)$. Now differentiate both sides,

$2 x f(x^2) - f(x) = f(x)$ Solve:

$x f(x^2) = f(x)$

Now, it seems like fucntions of the form $f(x)=\frac{c}{x}$ would solve this, but are these the only ones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How find this function $xf(x^2)=f(x),x>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019560/how-find-this-function-xfx2-fx-x0)

Comment: I agree with the argument for |x|<1, but am not sure it follows that f(x)=c/x for all x in real numbers

Comment: One more: You might be curious about how $g(0)$ (and continuity) can be defined at above citation... In fact, you can use almost same $\epsilon - \delta$ argument on $0<x_0<1$ by starting with f(1) = g(1) = $c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, yes. (continuing from comments)

Note that $g(x) = xf(x)$ is continuous at $x = 1\,$  and $\,\,g(x) = g(x^{2^n})$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let me prove the fact $g(x_0) = c$ for $\forall x_0>1$.

(Also note $g(1) = c$ since $g$ continuous at $x = 1$ and $g(x) = c\,$ on $\,x<1$.)

---

for $\epsilon >0$ , $\exists \delta >0$ such that $1<x<1+\delta$ implies $|g(x)-c|<\epsilon\,\,$.

Choose $N\in \mathbb{N}$ satisfies ${x_0}^{\frac{1}{2^N}} < 1+\delta$.

Then,
$$
|g(x_0) - c| = |g({x_0}^{\frac{1}{2^N}}) - c| <\epsilon 
$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $g(x_0) = c$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x)=xf(x)$. Then $g(x)=g(x^{2})$. Can you finish?

Comment: This looks wrong. Perhaps you meant $g(x) = xf(x)$? – But it's a duplicate anyway.

Comment: @MartinR Thank  you for pointing out.